# react native router flux back to the initial screen from the sub scene

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm trying to implement `logout` button on the profile page.

I have following routes defined.

```
<Router>
    <Scene initial  key='splashScreen' component={SplashScreen} title='Sayan' hideNavBar />
    <Scene key='loginScreen' component={LoginScreen} title='President Login' hideNavBar />
    <Scene key='drawer' component={NavigationDrawer} open={false}>
        <Scene key='drawerChildrenWrapper' hideNavBar>
            <Scene key='homeScreen' component={HomeScreen} title='Sayan' hideNavBar />
            <Scene key='createUserScreen' component={CreateUserScreen} title='Create a user' hideNavBar />   
            <Scene key='Profile' component={ProfileScreen} title='Profile' hideNavBar />
        </Scene>
    </Scene>
</Router>
```

What does the `logout` button handler look like, if i want to pop back to `splashScreen` or `loginScreen` scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should close the current screen and show the loginScreen:
    Actions.popTo('loginScreen');

Actions.pop closes current Scene. Actions.popTo is essentially two commands... Actions.pop() and Actions.loginScreen()

Comment: Thanks! But it still doesn't work in the way I want. here's the screen flow. [splashScreen]->[loginScreen]->[drawer.drawerChildrenWrapper.homeScreen]->[draw.drawerChildrenWrapper.Profile].  Now when users log out on either from `homescreen` or `Profile` scene, the scene stack should be [splahScreen]->[loginScreen]

Comment: Did you try nesting the loginScreen Scene inside the splashScreen Scene?

Comment: I didn't. How will that help to organize the scene stacks properly?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know what you mean by 'scene stack should be [splashScreen]-> [loginScreen]'

I personally use a Switch component to narrow the Scene tree for authenticated or not. There are a lot of ways to do things with this package and some of them don't work as you'd expect so give the documentation a good read-through. I'm still figuring out the nuances.

Answer (score 0):

you can use type="reset" in the next route

> in my case:

```
<Scene key="Wellcome"
   component={Wellcome}
   title="Wellcome"
   initial 
/>
<Scene key="Home"
   component={Home}
   title="Home"
   type='reset'
/>
```